# Alternative to singleton for unique resources

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, global-variables

I keep reading over and over again that one should avoid using singletons for various reasons. I'm wondering how to correctly handle a situation where a class represents a unique system resource. For example, a AudioOutput class using SDL. Since SDL_OpenAudio can only be open once at a time it makes no sense having more then one object of this type and it seems to me preventing accidentally making more then one object would actually be good.

Just wondering what experienced programmers think about this, am i missing another option ?

Comment: It also makes no sense to have more than one standard output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using design patterns wisely is a tricky questions, and it requires a lot of practice.

I have seen a lot of people using Singleton just because it "sort of" fits what they need to do. And this often results in disasters, for example in case of multi-threaded environments, or just as it was meant to hide a design flaw and needed a complete system redesign later on.

I'd say you need to think about a few things when considering Singleton:

- Do I really need to have only one instance of my object? Am I not trying to hide some design flaw?
- Does it make sense that my object can be accessed globally?

But I'd say don't spend too much time on it: it may not be always the best solution, but this is still an acceptable solution in some cases, and unless you're in a multi-threaded environment, you'll probably rarely have issues. It's mainly a design choice.

If you want to gain more knowledge about design patterns, I advise [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612), which is pretty much the reference on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for the book, hopefully it will help me understand oop better :)

Answer (score 9):

One of the problems with Singleton is that most often its usage breaks the Inversion of Control principle (or Dependency Inversion in terms of [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)).

Singleton doesn't only prevent creating more than one object, it also exposes this object to be accessed from everywhere in your code. This is bad, because if you decide to change the way your object is created/accessed, you would have to change all the places in your code which expect, for example, that they should access it via a static `SingletonClass.GetInstance()`.

Also, when you implement unit testing, it's often needed to use mocks instead of real objects. In your situation, if you wanted some module to be unit-tested, and if that module accessed a real audio output via `SingletonClass.GetInstance()`, it would become very hard to substitute the real audio output with a stub.

On the other hand, if your module acquired the audio output object via [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (e.g., as a parameter passed to constructor), then while testing, instead of the real audio output object, you could inject a stub which implemented the same interface.

Of course, on the level where you **inject** such objects, you could use singleton to ensure there's only one instance at a time. The main point is that the underlying code should not care about how many objects there can be or how they are acquired - it just works with what's injected.

So as a bottom line, you can use Singleton if you really think it's needed, but don't allow it to be accessed as global state.

Answer (score 2):

You are OK with a singleton as long as:

- you are not in a multithreaded environment (multiple threads accessing the singleton)
- you *are* in a multithreaded environment and implemneted proper protection within the singleton
- the singleton object is not defined in more than one dynamically loaded modules